# which type file_get_content() Return?

Tags: php, html

i have simple code in which i get the content of a file and whant to save it in browser
local Db in HTML5
here the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 100 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {

tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log, content LONGBLOB not       null)');

<?php   

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO LOGS(id, log,content)
         VALUES('5','abc','" . mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents("43.mp3")) . "')";

?>


 var v= "<?php echo $sql1;?>";
 console.log(v);
 tx.executeSql(v);
 msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
 document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;

});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
 msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
 document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
}
     }, null);
  });

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="status" name="status">No Data </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

it not insert record i think file_get_content()
return the content list but not a proper string format
console.log(v); point out illegal synex

Comment: You are executing the string that was tored in $sql1. I think you want $sql2. Name your variables in a better way. Also, putting possibly several megabytes of data into a html document is in many cases **bad**. Load the mp3 file when required using Ajax/whatever and display a loading indicator in that time.

Comment: @Rangad actually it my client requirement that save all files into browser Db so that he can play files in offline mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_escape_string()` to escape for Javascript Database API. That escape is not safe for Javascript to call as a string.

Instead, I think you should use `base64_encode` in PHP to encode the mp3 binary. For example:

```
<?php   

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO LOGS(id, log,content)
         VALUES('5','abc','" . 
         base64_encode(file_get_contents("43.mp3")) . "')";

?>
```

String in base64 format should be save for Javascript, include Database API and `console.log(v)`. You should then [load the mp3 data with Audio API's readAsDataURL()](http://www.michael-gerhaeuser.de/?f=fileapi/readme.html) and play it.

Comment: In fact, `mp3` files are large. For performance sake, it's probably better to load them with AJAX then to load it as inline javascript. But that's another issue.